# I dont know how to search for a matching row with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am having trouble with pdo and php because I am a php noob and dont know much.  I am trying to connect to a database(which I did)then search the query (or something) for a matching string.  Basically so a user cant make a account with the same username. This is the connection code.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users;","root","");
```

and here is the confirmation code that is not working :(

```
                $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY username';
            foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
                if($username1 !== $row['username']) {
                    $acceptCounter++;
                    $username = $_GET['username'];
                }
            }
```

please help me :)

Comment: Did you try reading the manual ? it has some pretty simple examples for exactly what you need:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: First of all, define a `UNIQUE` on the `username` column in the table to prevent if from happening. You then have the option to try an `INSERT` and just catch an exception, or do your query with a `WHERE username='desired username'` (use a prepared statement), if that has 0 rows, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several suggestions to you.

1. First of all, add a unique index to your `users` table, like this:
   `ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE(username)`
   After this you won't need to worry about name duplication: mySQL will throw an error (but please be careful and handle errors properly).
2. Use the `WHERE` clause as suggested in a comment. So you won't need to loop through a large number of rows to find one single row.
3. Use parameterized queries and prepared statements. As you're using PDO (which is, I believe, one of the best things you could do with PHP and MySQL), this shouldn't be a hard thing to do. So you'll be secure from (most of the) SQL injections.
4. Use `PDO->fetch()` and `PDO->fetchAll()`. Queries in loops are a really bad thing to do because this slows down your whole website.